# List of figures has weird space between chapters - Pandoc/LaTeX/markdown/Eisvogel

Tags: pdf, latex, markdown, pandoc

[list of figure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NXdRt.png)

Hello!

I currently have a problem with my list of figures, I have some rather strange spaces between certain chapters (# Title). My friend also uses the eisvogel template but he doesn't have this problem, any idea where it could be coming from?

```
$if(lof)$
\listoffigures
$endif$
```

I've tried various things listed in the guide but also here, but nothing works.

reproducible example: https://pastebin.com/jCmGUd4e

Comment: Can we please get a [mcve]?

Comment: @Robert Sure! Updated the post! :) And oh well just found that "classoption:book" break everything regarding list of figure.